# Why wasn't Daredevil bothered by this event?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

### Spoilers for both seasons of *Daredevil* below.

In "Speak of the Devil," Daredevil kills Nobu after a brutal duel.

[image]

Murdock never talks about this, even when discussing murder with his priest.

> LANTOM: That thing... brought you here last time [killing Fisk] ... didn't go so well?
>
> MURDOCK: Not so much.
>
> LANTOM: The man... you talked of... did you...
>
> MURDOCK: No, I didn't kill him. (sighs deeply) But I tried to.
>
> LANTOM: And are you disappointed that you didn't succeed... or maybe a little relieved?

His various discussions with the Punisher seem to imply that he has never killed anyone before.

For example, from "New York's Finest,"

> DAREDEVIL: I don't kill anyone.

We later learn that Nobu came back to life, but Murdock did not know that at the time.

While the act was self-defense, and arguably justified, it seems odd that he never mentions it again.

Why did Daredevil forget about or act like Nobu's death never happened? Has there been any Word of God on this?

Comment: We don't know that he *didn't* feel anything for this event. We just know that he didn't comment or bring it up with anyone. Mentioning Fisk is one thing, mentioning a ninja-assassin is another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is discussed in a [2015 interview between IGN and showrunner Steven DeKnight](http://in.ign.com/daredevil-1/74985/feature/marvels-daredevil-season-1-spoiler-conversation-with-showrun). DeKnight's justification is that Nobu's death was basically an accident, and really more Nobu's own fault than anyone else's:

> **DeKnight:** We never wanted [Daredevil] to intentionally kill anyone; he can certainly put a guy in a coma, y'know? And with Nobu, it was more of a deflection, so he wasn't actively trying to kill Nobu. Nobu kind of brought it on himself.